# Convert Video to binary Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to convert video to binary data so I can send them to the server using Alamofire.upload, I try the below code but it did not work from me and I have also try different mimeType

```
if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? NSURL {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    //guard let bytes = try? NSData(contentsOf: videoURL as URL) else { return }
    guard let videoData = try? Data(contentsOf: videoURL as URL) else { return }
}

multipartFormData.append(fileData!, withName: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "video/quicktime")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if let videoFileURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL { 
     let bytesArr = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: videoFileURL) 
}
```

Comment: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(NSData, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)'